# "дочерям их не будет ни в пути, ни при Дворе никаких обид"

Tags: история-языка, лексикон

The *[ИСТОРИЧЕСКИЙ ОЧЕРК ГЛАВНЕЙШИХ СОБЫТИЙ В КАМЧАТКЕ. 1650—1855](http://www.npacific.ru/np/library/publikacii/historykam/istkam1-1.htm)* by Sgibnev, 1869, contains this passage:

> Января 13-го 1758 г. прибыл в Нижнекамчатск штат-фурьер Шахтуров для выбора ко двору камчадальских девиц. Он привез к камчатским тоенам Высочайший рескрипт, в котором была выдержана цель поездки в Камчатку Шахтурова и уверение в том, что дочерям их не будет ни в пути, ни при Дворе никаких обид. Выбрав шесть молодых дочерей тоенов, Шахтуров в том же году отправился с ним в Петербург, куда прибыл только через год, потому, что всем девицам пришлось разрешиться в пути от бремени, благодаря вниманию к ним Шахтурова.

I can't quite discern what Shakhturov promised the girls' fathers to avoid. Was this outcome precisely the *обид* he supposedly meant?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> “дочерям их не будет ни в пути, ни при Дворе никаких обид”

I am not a native speaker, but it is pretty straightforward, so I cannot miss the rare opportunity to answer: "Their daughters won't suffer any injustice or mistreatment on their way to the Royal Court or at it." The promise is of a very general character and is, essentially, "Don't worry, everything will be fine, your daughters won't have any reason to complain."

Answer (score 8):

*Обида* in this (quite archaic) sense means "wrong, harm, mischief".

Shahkturov promised the girls' fathers that they (the daughters) will be treated well and no harm would be done to them.

The Synodal translation of the Bible gives us several examples of this usage:

> - Ты видишь, Господи, обиду мою; рассуди дело мое //  O Lord, thou hast seen my wrong: judge thou my cause.
> - Так говорит Господь Бог: довольно вам, князья Израилевы! отложите обиды и угнетения и творите суд и правду // Thus saith the Lord GOD; Let it suffice you, O princes of Israel: remove violence and spoil, and execute judgment and justice
> - У тебя отца и мать злословят, пришельцу делают обиду среди тебя, сироту и вдову притесняют у тебя //  In thee have they set light by father and mother: in the midst of thee have they dealt by oppression with the stranger: in thee have they vexed the fatherless and the widow

Answer (score 4):

There is a "between line" meaning in this case: sexial abuse. Shakhturov promised that girls would not be forced to become a lover or a wife to anybody (it was not uncommon for high lords to abuse some province girls). But he didn't quite held that promise by himself as you can understand ("внимание" here means sexual contact)